# Memory Access Error with a JNA Structure that contains a pointer to an array of pointers

Tags: pointers, constructor, jna

Below is the code I am working with:
C API:

```
typedef struct {
    int matId;
    int nMatNameSize;
    char* materialName;
    int isHyMat;
    lDVDetailOutput* dVOutputs;
} innerStruct;

typedef struct {
    int nMaterials;
    innerStruct** moreDetailOutputs;
} detailOutput;

int LDValues(const char* version,
             const detailInput* input,
             detailOutput* output);
```

JNA Declarations:

```
public static class lDVDetailOutput extends Structure {
    public static class ByReference extends lDVDetailOutput implements Structure.ByReference{}

    int dValue;
    int nVars;
    yetAnotherStructure.ByReference vars;

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[] { 
            "dValue", "nVars", "yetAnotherStructure", });
    }
}

public static class jInnerStruct extends Structure{
    int matId;
    int nMatNameSize;
    String materialName;
    int isHyMat;
    lDVDetailOutput.ByReference dValueOutputs;

    jInnerStruct() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[] { 
            "matId", "nMatNameSize", "materialName",
            "isHyMat", "dValueOutputs", });
    }
}

public static class jDetailOutput extends Structure {
    public static class ByReference extends detailOutput implements Structure.ByReference{}

    int nMaterials;
    Pointer moreDetailOutputs; // jInnerStruct**

    public jDetailOutput(Pointer p) {
        super(p);
        read();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[] { 
            "nMaterials", "moreDetailOutputs", });
    }
}

public static LDValues(final String inputString,
                       final jDetailInput.ByReference inputValues,
                       jDetailOutput.ByReference outputValues) {}
```

In my main program I have the following code:

```
jDetailOutput.ByReference recvDetailOutput = new jDetailOutput.ByReference();

int success = LDValues(stringObject, inputValues, recvDetailOutput);

Pointer[] myDetailOutputPointers = recvDetailOutput.moreDetailOutputs.getPointerArray(0, recvDetailOutput.detailOutput.nMaterials);

jInnerStruct interimLMDO = new jInnerStruct(matDetailOutputPointers[0]);
```

I am getting a Memory Access error during the read() call in the jDetailOutput(Pointer P) constructor.  Specifically when trying to read the dValueOutputs member of jInnerStruct.

Using the Eclipse debugger I see that dValueOutputs has a value of null.  I do see that nMaterials in jDetailOutput has a correct value in it.

Do I need to create a different constructor for jInnerStruct?

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: Is any further documentation provided for `LDValues` or the structs? Do you have a working prototype written in C?

Comment: Also remember to provide an implementation for [`getFieldOrder`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.5.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Structure.html#getFieldOrder--).

Comment: I have implemented the getFieldOrder already.

Comment: I do not have a working prototype in C at this time.  What are you looking for as further documentation?

Comment: Be sure to the `getFieldOrder`-implementing version in your answer. The documentation would tell whether it expects any structs' members to point to pre-allocated memory and whether they're just pointers or actually arrays etc.

Comment: I've added the getFieldOrder function to the Structures.  I also noticed that the declaration of LDValues was incorrect so I corrected that, added ".ByReference". @cubrr

Comment: Let me see what I can provide as far as documentation:   `moreDetailOutputs` is expected to be an array containing pointers to `jInnerStruct`.

Comment: The basic field type is `Pointer`, then you use `Pointer.getPointer(0)` to get the first `struct*`.  You can use this pointer to initialize a Java-side `Structure`.  `Pointer.getPointerArray(0, len)` may be used to get a full array of the saved pointers. JNA can often do the translation automatically (see the [FAQ](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.md#when-should-i-use-structurebyreference-structurebyvalue-structure) for hints on how to handle different variations).